# SQL compute Academic Year from Semester and Year

Tags: sql, r, sorting, date

I am new to SQL and writing in R markdown. I am trying to query a database by academic year (e.g., AY2022-23) when I only have a semester( Fall, Spring, Summer) and a year(e.g., 2021, 2022, 2023) to work with. I have tried the following to pull the 2022-2023 academic year, but I am stuck if I need to pull a more considerable period of time.

```
SELECT * 
FROM DTA_Set1
WHERE (Year = '2022' AND TERM = 'Fall')
   OR (Year = '2023' AND TERM = 'Spring')
   OR (Year = '2023' AND TERM = 'Summer')
```

Sample Data in R (since I don't know how to make a sample data set SQL)

```
Sam_Data <- data.frame(TERM= sample(c("FALL", "SPRING", "Summer"), size= 2000, replace = T, prob=c(.6, .3,.1)), Year= sample(c("2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019"),size= 2000, replace = T))
```

To be clear, the academic year starts in the fall and continues until the following summer. So Fall 22, Spring 23, and Summer 23 comprise the 2022-2023 academic year.

Any ideas will be most helpful!

Comment: [code block]s have triple backticks _on their own line_, nothing can be on the same line as the triple backticks. I've edited your question for you.

Comment: If the `Year` column in your `DTA_Set1` table is a numeric (as it should be), then you should **not** use single quotes when comparing - that will cause unnecessary implicit type conversions. Use `WHERE (Year = 2022 AND .....` instead - just the number, no single or double quotes necessary !

Comment: @marc_s Thank you for catching that; I have very little knowledge of SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll demo a query using `sqldf`. Most DBMSes support the `substr` and `cast` functions either verbatim like this or in something close.

```r
sqldf::sqldf("
  select *,
    'AY' || (case when TERM in ('SPRING', 'Summer') then (cast(Year as int) - 1) || '-' || substr(Year, 3, 2)
                  else Year || '-' || (cast(substr(Year, 3, 2) as int) + 1)
                  end) as AcademicYear
  from Sam_Data
  limit 10")
#      TERM Year AcademicYear
# 1    FALL 2016    AY2016-17
# 2  SPRING 2018    AY2017-18
# 3    FALL 2016    AY2016-17
# 4    FALL 2019    AY2019-20
# 5  SPRING 2018    AY2017-18
# 6  SPRING 2016    AY2015-16
# 7    FALL 2019    AY2019-20
# 8    FALL 2019    AY2019-20
# 9    FALL 2018    AY2018-19
# 10 SPRING 2015    AY2014-15
```

Assuming you want to filter to a specific year, then you can use a [common table expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL)):

```r
sqldf::sqldf("
  with mycte as (
    select *,
      'AY' || (case when TERM in ('SPRING', 'Summer') then (cast(Year as int) - 1) || '-' || substr(Year, 3, 2)
                    else Year || '-' || (cast(substr(Year, 3, 2) as int) + 1)
                    end) as AcademicYear
    from Sam_Data
  )
  select * from mycte where AcademicYear = 'AY2016-17'
  limit 10")
#      TERM Year AcademicYear
# 1    FALL 2016    AY2016-17
# 2    FALL 2016    AY2016-17
# 3    FALL 2016    AY2016-17
# 4    FALL 2016    AY2016-17
# 5    FALL 2016    AY2016-17
# 6  SPRING 2017    AY2016-17
# 7    FALL 2016    AY2016-17
# 8    FALL 2016    AY2016-17
# 9  Summer 2017    AY2016-17
# 10   FALL 2016    AY2016-17
```

Comment: @r2evens, I can't get this to work. I have removed the sqldf function and the mycte bit; since I am connecting to a database. The error message I am getting is an incorrect syntax near ' | ' Failed to execute SQL chunk.  ```SELECT *, ('AY' || (case when MatTerm in ('Spring', 'Summer') then MatYear -1)|| '-'|| substr(MatYear,3,2)
  else MatYear || '-' || substr(MatYear, 3, 2) + 1) 
  end) as AcaYr
  from vwAppStuPrg
  Where AcaYr= 'AY2017-18'```

Comment: what DBMS are you using? some have different ways to do string-concatenation. (BTW, the use of a CTE should work on most if not all DBMSes, it's a fairly standard mechanism.)

Comment: @r2evens I am using a SQL chunk in R-markdown.

Comment: As far as i can tell, a SQL chunk in an R-markdown document is only going to style the code to make it look pretty; if you want it to _execute_ the query, then it needs to connect to some form of SQL database, whether it be file-based such as SQLite/DuckDB, or a remote server such as postgres, mariadb, sql-server, or something else.

Comment: I was off last week. I am still getting the same syntax error.

Comment: That's a bummer. I asked what DBMS you're using, "chunk" is not a valid answer afaict: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/language-engines.html#sql says that the connection needs to be an object that was created using `DBI::dbConnect` and either set once globally or passed in each SQL chunk header. If it's a db that I can mimic here (in docker) then I'm willing to look at it, but atm the code in my answer works in at least SQLite; other database engines have different casting and string-concatenation syntax.

Comment: I am using `dbconnect`; I have set up the connection in the first R chunk and wrote the SQL code in a separate chunk.  that is how I have always set up the connection to the databases. and have never had a problem until I tried creating a variable in the `SELECT` Command,

Comment: Okay, since I can't help you on a dbms I don't know, I'll give you this so that you can figure it out yourself: `||` is string-concatenation, so `'AB' || 'CD'` should return `'ABCD'`; `substr` is a substring operator, so `substr('2017',3,2)` should return `'17'`; and `cast` converts a column from one class to another, so `cast('2017' as int)` should return `2017` (an int), and `cast(2017 as char(4))` should return `'2017'` (a string). Each DBMS may do these three (and many others) operators slightly differently. Best of luck, perhaps your DBA can help you with this step.

Comment: thank you for the help! I will add an answer to this post when I figure it out.